# How to implement NSTimer in a parameterised function?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm writing a program for XML parsing. The parsing process is working well but I need to repeat the function after each 25 seconds. I tried `NSTimer` but it's not working for me. When it's invoked it shows an SIGABRT error. The function, which I need to invoke after each 25 seconds, is given below:

```
-(id)loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)filePath :(NSTimer *) timer
{
    categories =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; 
    parser =[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:myData];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return  self;
}
```

And The method I used to set the timer is given below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cd_catalog" ofType:@"xml"];


    NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 25.0 target: self
                                                      selector: @selector(loadXMLByURL:filePath:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

    xmlParser=[[XMLParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:filePath:myTimer];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Please tell me what's wrong with my code and also tell me if there is any other method available for the process with an example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have `return self;` in your method?

Comment: Why do you want to parse the same file over and over every 25 seconds? Why not parse it once and save the data?

Comment: @rmaddy I believe the XML file will be provided from a remote source and he will listen for changes in the file or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector you use for the timer can only take one parameter and that will be the timer. You can't pass the filePath to the timer's selector.

Remove the filePath parameter and make the path an instance variable.

```
-(id)loadXML {
    categories =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; // filePath is an ivar
    parser =[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:myData];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return  self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // filePath is now an ivar
    filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cd_catalog" ofType:@"xml"];

    // The timer isn't needed by the selector so don't pass it
    NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:25.0 target:self
                                selector:@selector(loadXML) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    xmlParser=[[XMLParser alloc] loadXML];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Note: You should name each parameter. Your original method was named `loadXMLByURL::`. Note the two colons with nothing in between.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. Just curious, is there a particular reason for the `loadXML` method to return `self`? Couldn't it be just `(void)loadXML`?

Comment: It can be void. I believe he just returned self because that is how you did it in your code.

Comment: @Jsdodgers thanks for the clarification. It wasn't me by the way.

Comment: @tolgamorf It makes no sense to me to have `loadXML` return `self`. As was mentioned, I left it since that's how it was for some reason.

Comment: also, you can pass your filename parameter as userInfo argument:

`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:25.0 target:self
                                selector:@selector(loadXML) userInfo:filename repeats:YES]`

and retrieve it in your function via `-userInfo` method of passed in instance of `NSTimer`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is that you are passing it the selector @selector(loadXMLByURL:filePath:) which has two parameters but the NSTimer's selector must have only one parameter which is the timer itself.

From the docs on NSTimer:

`aSelector
The message to send to target when the timer fires. The selector must correspond to a method that returns void and takes a single argument. The timer passes itself as the argument to this method.`

You need to create a method that has only an NSTimer* (or id) as the parameter and get your filename from elsewhere.

Edit: Here is a link to the class reference for [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval%3atarget%3aselector%3auserInfo%3arepeats%3a).